# Select data based on records created_at column

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.3, aggregate, query-performance

I have two tables Keywords, ProjectReports:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/06ae3/1

As you can see in that example everything works fine, but I want to get more data from those 2 tables and I don't know how.

1. In the `position` column I would like to display only the smallest value and just one value instead of that array. ex: [1, 2, 3]  will be 1
2. As you can see there is the `keyword` with `id 4` which doesn't have any data in the `project_reports` table, in this case I would like to add the `value 0` in the `position column` and add the current day date in the `CREATED_AT` column.
3. Also I would like to display the position value for the same keywords, where `created_at` column from `project_reports` table had the value `now() - interval '1 day'; now() - interval '1 week'; now() - interval '1 mon'`, if there is no `position` for those days add `0`.

Expected output:

Keywords:

```
 ID: 1 name: test
 ID: 2 name: test1
 ID: 3 name: test2
```

Project_reports:

```
 ID: 1, keyword_id: 1, project_id: 1, position: 1, created_at: '2014-07-09'
 ID: 2, keyword_id: 1, project_id: 1, position: 2, created_at: '2014-07-09'
 ID: 3, keyword_id: 1, project_id: 1, position: 3, created_at: '2014-07-10'
 ID: 5, keyword_id: 1, project_id: 1, position: 4, created_at: '2014-07-10'
 ID: 6, keyword_id: 2, project_id: 1, position: 1, created_at: '2014-07-09'
```

After query

```
k_name: test, k_id: 1, p_id: 1, position 3, yesterday_position: 1, created_at: '2014-07-10'
k_name: test1, k_id: 2, p_id: 1, position 0, yesterday_position: 1, created_at: '2014-07-10'
k_name: test2, k_id: 3, p_id: 1, position 0, yesterday_position: 0, created_at: '2014-07-10'
k_name: test, k_id: 1, p_id: 1, position 1, yesterday_position: 0, created_at: '2014-07-09'
k_name: test1, k_id: 2, p_id: 1, position 1, yesterday_position: 0, created_at: '2014-07-09'
k_name: test2, k_id: 3, p_id: 1, position 0, yesterday_position: 0, created_at: '2014-07-09'
```

Comment: I don't see primary keys in your example. Those make a difference. Can we assume the `id` columns to be primary keys?

Comment: yes the `id` is the primary key, sorry for that.

Comment: OK, then your test data are flawed. Duplicate keys in `project_reports`. Please clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure, which keys are duplicated?

Comment: Did I guess what your are after for item 3? I'll add explanation if it solves the question.

Comment: thank you so much, item 3 is working as I expected. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi, I have a small problem that I don't know how to fix, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/864ca/3 please check line 58 - 59, and see that I've added a join table for keywords and projects `project_keyword` your query works great thank you for that, the problem that I have: `keyword 5` had `project_report` data only 1 day ago and 1 week ago, so it's actual output should be: `keyword_id: 5, project_id: 1, created_at: TodayDate, pos: 0 (it should add 0 when no data), yesterday_pos: 33, week_pos: 34, month_pos: 0`. As you can see I removed the `distinct on project_id and keyword_id` to get all the dates.

Comment: I suggest you start a new question for your new problem with all the necessary details. You can always link to this one for context. Comments are not the place for new questions.

Comment: This changes the whole approach. I suggest you start a new question for your new problem with all the necessary details. You can always link to this one for context. Comments are not the place for new questions. I think I have a radically new idea ...

Comment: you can check my new question at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71236/pull-data-from-multiple-tables-in-a-view-or-function also I realised few other things. Thank you

Comment: Found this by chance. [Check out how @replies works.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the slightly modified schema of my test [in the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/983a0/3).
Using actual primary keys and proper column names instead of `id`.

Also, you seem to be operating with dates exclusively. So I suggest to convert your `timestamp` columns to `date`.

#### Items 1 and 2

```
SELECT k.keyword_id
     , k.name
     , pr.project_id
     , COALESCE(min(pr.position), 0) AS pos
     , COALESCE(pr.created_at, now()::date) AS created_at
FROM   keyword             k 
LEFT   JOIN project_report pr USING (keyword_id)
GROUP  BY k.keyword_id, pr.project_id, pr.created_at
ORDER  BY keyword_id, created_at
;
```

- In Postgres 9.1 or later the pk column covers the whole table in `GROUP BY`.
- Use [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to replace possible `NULL` values.

#### A guess at item 3

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT k.keyword_id
        , k.name
        , pr.project_id
        , COALESCE(min(pr.position), 0) AS pos
        , COALESCE(pr.created_at, now()::date) AS created_at
   FROM   keyword   k 
   LEFT   JOIN project_report pr USING (keyword_id)
   GROUP  BY k.keyword_id, pr.project_id, pr.created_at
   )
, x AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (keyword_id, project_id) *
   FROM   cte
   ORDER  BY keyword_id, project_id, created_at DESC
   )
SELECT x.*
     , COALESCE(y.pos, 0) AS yesterday_pos 
     , COALESCE(w.pos, 0) AS week_pos 
     , COALESCE(m.pos, 0) AS month_pos 
FROM   x
LEFT   JOIN  cte y ON y.keyword_id = x.keyword_id
                  AND y.project_id = x.project_id
                  AND y.created_at = x.created_at - interval '1 day'
LEFT   JOIN  cte w ON w.keyword_id = x.keyword_id
                  AND w.project_id = x.project_id
                  AND w.created_at = x.created_at - interval '1 week'
LEFT   JOIN  cte m ON m.keyword_id = x.keyword_id
                  AND m.project_id = x.project_id
                  AND m.created_at = x.created_at - interval '1 month'
;
```

#### Explain

1. In CTE `cte` produce daily aggregates per `(k.keyword_id, pr.project_id)`.
2. In CTE `x` pick the latest day per `(k.keyword_id, pr.project_id)`.
3. In the outer query `LEFT JOIN` the latest day `x` to `cte` multiple times to retrieve past values from the same `(k.keyword_id, pr.project_id)` for 1 day / week / month earlier.

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/983a0/3)