# Pull data from multiple tables in a view or function

Tags: postgresql, performance, pivot, query-performance

There are 3 tables from which I need to pull data, and print it in a specific way.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/59481/8

Refer to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/70037/select-data-based-on-records-created-at-column) to see how the query was produced. The version in the fiddle working partially, but I need to modify the query to produce a different output.

I have the table `project_report` which is storing data for `keyword`:

```
1. If a keyword has data for a particular day it will store it in `project_report`
2. A keyword might have no data to store for a particular day.
3. A keyword might store multiple rows of data for a particular day (the data is uniq)
4. A keyword might not have data for a particular day, but it might have for a different day.
```

I believe to solve my problem a DB function will be the best approach, because I would like to be able to specify a date and get all the data from `project_reports` for each `keyword`.

I don't know how to write this query, to produces the below results, also I don't know what will be better, to have a `view` or a `db function`, I think that with a `view` in order to select a specific date, I will need for each keyword and each date to produce those outputs. The other problem is that I would also like to use these results in a chart, which will take the data for a range, for that I think a view is better, then calling a function n times.

---

So if `keyword_id: 1` has in the `project_report`:

```
ID: 1, keyword_id: 1, project_id: 1, position: 1, created_at: '2014-07-09'
ID: 2, keyword_id: 1, project_id: 1, position: 2, created_at: '2014-07-09'
```

For the selected date `2014-07-09` I should get (please see that position will be the smallest position instead of [1, 2]):

```
keyword_id: 1, project_id: 1, position: 1, yesterday_pos: 0, last_week_pos: 0, last_month_pos:0 created_at: '2014-07-09'
```

If `keyword_id: 2` has in the `project_report`:

```
ID: 3, keyword_id: 2, project_id: 1, position: 3, created_at: '2014-07-09'
ID: 4, keyword_id: 2, project_id: 1, position: 4, created_at: '2014-07-08'
ID: 5, keyword_id: 2, project_id: 1, position: 5, created_at: '2014-07-08'
ID: 6, keyword_id: 2, project_id: 1, position: 4, created_at: '2014-07-03'
```

For the selected date `2014-07-09` I should get:

```
keyword_id: 2, project_id: 1, position: 3, yesterday_pos: 4, last_week_pos: 4, last_month_pos: 0 created_at: '2014-07-09'
```

If `keyword_id: 3` has in the `project_report`:

```
ID: 7, keyword_id: 3, project_id: 1, position: 10, created_at: '2014-07-08'
ID: 8, keyword_id: 3, project_id: 1, position: 11, created_at: '2014-07-03'
```

For the selected date `2014-07-09` I should get:

```
keyword_id: 3, project_id: 1, position: 0, yesterday_pos: 10, last_week_pos: 11, last_month_pos: 0 created_at: '2014-07-09'
```

If `keyword_id: 4` has in the `project_report`:

```
`nothing`
```

For the selected date `2014-07-09` I should get:

```
keyword_id: 4, project_id: 1, position: 0, yesterday_pos: 0, last_week_pos: 0, last_month_pos: 0 created_at: '2014-07-09'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest a radically new approach with `crosstab()` from the additional module [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html). You need to install it once per database. Detailed instructions:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

```
SELECT k.name, keyword_id, project_id, now()::date AS the_date
     , t AS today, y As yesterday, w AS week, m AS month
FROM   crosstab(
   $$
   SELECT rn
        , pk.keyword_id
        , pk.project_id
        , d.created_at
        , COALESCE(pr.pos, 0) AS pos
   FROM  (SELECT *, row_number() OVER () AS rn FROM project_keyword) pk
   CROSS  JOIN (
      VALUES
         (now()::date)
       , (now()::date - 1)
       , (now()::date - 7)
       ,((now() - interval '1 month')::date)
     ) d(created_at)
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT keyword_id
           , project_id
           , created_at::date AS created_at
           , min(position) AS pos
      FROM   project_report
      GROUP  BY keyword_id, project_id, created_at::date
      ) pr USING (keyword_id, project_id, created_at)
   ORDER  BY pk.rn, d.created_at
   $$

  ,$$
   VALUES
         (now()::date)
       , (now()::date - 1)
       , (now()::date - 7)
       , ((now() - interval '1 month')::date)
   $$
   ) ct (rn int, keyword_id int, project_id int
       , t int, y int, w int, m int)
JOIN   keyword k USING (keyword_id);
```

Returns:

```
name    keyword_id   project_id   the_date     today   yesterday   week   month
Cheese  1            1            2014-07-11   1       1           1      0
Monitor 2            1            2014-07-11   2       2           2      0
Apple   3            1            2014-07-11   9       9           9      0
Apple1  4            1            2014-07-11   0       0           0      0
Iphone  5            1            2014-07-11   0       33          34     0
```

#### Explain

- We need a single unique column per group for `crosstab()`. Since you don't have that per `(keyword_id int, project_id)` I am adding a surrogate key with `row_number()` to `project_keyword`.
- `JOIN` that to a set of dates you are interested in (today, yesterday etc.). One row per date.
- `LEFT JOIN` to `project_reports` to attach the position for each date if available. Default to 0 with `COALESCE`.
- Cross-tabulate to get a single row with one position column per given date.
- Finally `JOIN` to `keyword` just to add the `name`. Add the current date and remove `rn` from the result while being at it.

Aside: "name" is not a good name. I'd use something descriptive instead.

Comment: `(keyword_id, project_id, created_at)` here I get `common column name "created_at" appears more than once in left table` but If I remove it is working fine, It could be because I have on the `project_keyword` a column `created_at`?

Comment: @uhn-nohn: Yes, in this case the column name is ambiguous and you need to switch to explicit `ON` syntax in the join condition instead of the shorter `USING`.

Comment: What is the best way of creating a variable instead of now()::date, so I can pass a date into that variable, and get data based on its value?

Comment: @uhn-nohn: Create an SQL function with a `date` parameter and `RETURNS TABLE` and replace `now()::date` with `$1`. Examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862936/return-rows-from-a-pl-pgsql-function/11867138#11867138, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401749/pass-in-where-parameters-to-postgresql-view/11402415#11402415. If you are still stuck, write a new *question* here. Comments are not the place for new questions.

Comment: I already have a question on here, I tried to the function, but I got stuck not knowing what type to return, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71429/how-to-pass-a-parameter-into-a-function