# How to pass a parameter into a function

Tags: postgresql, view, functions

At the moment I have a view created, [see it here in the answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71236/pull-data-from-multiple-tables-in-a-view-or-function). How can I create a function based on that `crosstab()` query , so I can pass a date, and get data for the specific date?

Also is it good practice to call that function multiple times and pass different dates to fill a chart (for example)?

Comment: As for your additional question: Calling it a couple of times is fine. For a big chart or repeated use, I would create a separate query / function. Depends on circumstances.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: If he wants to work with the data and join it with other results, creating a view might be a better idea? He can still use the view in the function and put indexes on it to speed up queries.

Comment: @few: You cannot "put indexes" on a view. Performance of a view is roughly the same as performance of a function or a plain query. The best strategy depends on exact requirements.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: it takes around 7/8 ms to get the results for one day (and this is for just 3 to 5% of the date that I intent to use this on) plus that I intend to get the data for a range of dates. It will be better to duplicate the data into another table?

Comment: That's really hard to tell. Might be worth another question with all relevant details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest an SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(_date date)
  RETURNS TABLE (
   name       text  -- types have to match your actual types!
 , keyword_id int
 , project_id int
 , the_date   date
 , today      int
 , yesterday  int
 , week       int
 , month      int) AS
$func$

SELECT k.name, f.keyword_id, f.project_id, _date -- AS the_date -- col alias irrelevant
     , f.t AS today, f.y As yesterday, f.w AS week, f.m AS month
FROM   crosstab(

    -- crosstab function from previous question here
    -- http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71266/3684

   ) f (rn int, keyword_id int, project_id int
       , t int, y int, w int, m int)
JOIN   keyword k USING (keyword_id);

$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM foo('2014-07-07');
```

Replace all occurrences of `now()::date` with your input parameter named `_date`.
 In Postgres 9.1 or older use the positional parameter `$1` in SQL functions (which can be used in any version).

More code examples:

- [Return rows from a PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862936/return-rows-from-a-pl-pgsql-function/11867138#11867138)
- [Pass In “WHERE” parameters to PostgreSQL View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401749/pass-in-where-parameters-to-postgresql-view/11402415#11402415)

#### Tricky detail

The `crosstab()` function takes query *strings* as parameters. Function parameters are not visible inside `crosstab()`. So you need to pass in the date values as *string literals*!
I suggest the function **[`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)** for convenience. For example, the **second parameter** becomes:

```
,format('VALUES(%L::date), (%L), (%L), (%L)'
        , $1, $1 - 1, $1 - 7, ($1 - interval '1 month')::date
       )
```

instead of:

```
,$$
 VALUES
       (now()::date)
     , (now()::date - 1)
     , (now()::date - 7)
     , ((now() - interval '1 month')::date)
 $$
```

### Complete code

#### SQL function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo_sql(_date date)
  RETURNS TABLE (
   name       text
 , keyword_id int
 , project_id int
 , the_date   date
 , today      int
 , yesterday  int
 , week       int
 , month      int) AS
$func$
BEGIN

SELECT k.name, f.keyword_id, f.project_id, _date
     , f.t, f.y, f.w, f.m
FROM   crosstab (
   $$
   SELECT rn
        , pk.keyword_id
        , pk.project_id
        , d.created_at
        , COALESCE(pr.pos, 0)
   FROM  (SELECT *, row_number() OVER () AS rn FROM project_keyword) pk
   CROSS  JOIN (
       $$
    || format('VALUES(%L::date), (%L), (%L), (%L)'
              , $1, $1 - 1, $1 - 7, ($1 - interval '1 month')::date)
   || $$
     ) d(created_at)
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT keyword_id
           , project_id
           , created_at::date AS created_at
           , min(position) AS pos
      FROM   project_report
      GROUP  BY keyword_id, project_id, created_at::date
      ) pr USING (keyword_id, project_id, created_at)
   ORDER  BY pk.rn, d.created_at
   $$

  ,format('VALUES(%L::date), (%L), (%L), (%L)'
              , $1, $1 - 1, $1 - 7, ($1 - interval '1 month')::date)
   ) f (rn int, keyword_id int, project_id int
       , t int, y int, w int, m int)
JOIN   keyword k USING (keyword_id);

END
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

#### PL/pgSQL function

Shorter, reusing the `VALUES` expression. Probably a bit faster, too.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo_plpgsql(_date date)
  RETURNS TABLE (name text, keyword_id int, project_id int, the_date date
               , today int, yesterday int, week int, month int) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _dates text := format('VALUES(%L::date), (%L), (%L), (%L)'
                        , $1, $1 - 1, $1 - 7, ($1 - interval '1 month')::date);
BEGIN

SELECT k.name, f.keyword_id, f.project_id, _date, f.t, f.y, f.w, f.m
FROM   crosstab (
  'SELECT rn
        , pk.keyword_id
        , pk.project_id
        , d.created_at
        , COALESCE(pr.pos, 0)
   FROM  (SELECT *, row_number() OVER () AS rn FROM project_keyword) pk
   CROSS  JOIN (
       ' || _dates || '
     ) d(created_at)
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT keyword_id
           , project_id
           , created_at::date AS created_at
           , min(position) AS pos
      FROM   project_report
      GROUP  BY keyword_id, project_id, created_at::date
      ) pr USING (keyword_id, project_id, created_at)
   ORDER  BY pk.rn, d.created_at'

  ,_dates
   ) f (rn int, keyword_id int, project_id int, t int, y int, w int, m int)
JOIN   keyword k USING (keyword_id);

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### CTE

For completeness, the "same" without persisting a function, with [CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html):

```
WITH d(day)   AS (SELECT '2014-07-07'::date)  -- provide your date here
,    v(dates) AS (
   SELECT format('VALUES(%L::date), (%L), (%L), (%L)'
                 , day, day - 1, day - 7
                 ,(day - interval '1 month')::date)
   FROM d
   )
SELECT k.name, f.keyword_id, f.project_id, d.day AS the_date
     , f.t AS today, f.y As yesterday, f.w AS week, f.m AS month
FROM   crosstab (
  'SELECT rn
        , pk.keyword_id
        , pk.project_id
        , d.created_at
        , COALESCE(pr.pos, 0) AS pos
   FROM  (SELECT *, row_number() OVER () AS rn FROM project_keyword) pk
   CROSS  JOIN (
       ' || (SELECT dates FROM v) || '
     ) d(created_at)
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT keyword_id
           , project_id
           , created_at::date AS created_at
           , min(position) AS pos
      FROM   project_report
      GROUP  BY keyword_id, project_id, created_at::date
      ) pr USING (keyword_id, project_id, created_at)
   ORDER  BY pk.rn, d.created_at'

  ,(SELECT dates FROM v)
   ) f (rn int, keyword_id int, project_id int
       , t int, y int, w int, m int)
JOIN   keyword k USING (keyword_id);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, it`s partially working, but when I change the date for yesterday lets say, all the (today, yesterday, week, month) are empty, I know is because of ` (now()::date), (now()::date - 1), (now()::date - 7),((now() - interval '1 month')::date)`, and I tried changing now()::date with `$1` and with `_data` also I tried formatting it as I did for the second values, it still didn't work.

Comment: @uhn-nohn: Did you consider what I posted in the chapter "Tricky detail"? I added complete code examples to clarify.

Comment: @uhn-nohn: For completeness, I added a CTE version.