# Consolidate multiple rows into single row

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, pivot, aggregate-filter

In PostgreSQL 9.5, I have a table named `reports`:

```
CREATE TABLE public.reports (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  id_station character(11) NOT NULL,
  date date NOT NULL,
  element character(4) NOT NULL,
  value smallint NOT NULL
);
```

For each station (`id_station` column) and each day (`date` column), I *may* have multiple value types (element column) : `TMIN`, `TMAX`, `TAVG` (sometimes these values don't exist: I may have only a `TMIN` and a `TMAX` for a given day).

Here is a (fake) sample:

```
22;"FR069029001";"1925-01-01";"TMAX";130
23;"FR069029001";"1925-01-01";"TMIN";-25
24;"FR069029001";"1925-01-01";"TAVG";0
```

I would like to consolidate these values in one single row for each station and each day using this table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.reports_con (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
id_station character(11) NOT NULL,
date date NOT NULL,
tmin smallint,
tmax smallint,
tavg smallint
);
```

I would like to achieve this result:

```
454;"FR069029001";"1925-01-01";-25;130;0
```

How to consolidate the data this way in PostgreSQL? With `CREATE TABLE AS`?

I know it has to be a recursive query like this (human language) :

```
For each day:
    For each station:
        Find values for TMIN, TMAX, TAVG
Insert the results in reports_con in a single row with day and station
```

I begin learning SQL and would like to achieve this within PostgreSQL (not with Python or a programming language). Can you please help me?

Answer (score 4):

Since the target table obviously exists, `CREATE TABLE AS` is unrelated to the solution. And you certainly don't need a recursive query, either.

For just three columns you might use conditional aggregates:

```
INSERT INTO reports_con (id_station, date, tmin, tmax, tavg)
SELECT id_station, date
     , min(value) FILTER (WHERE element = 'TMIN') AS tmin
     , min(value) FILTER (WHERE element = 'TMAX') AS tmax
     , min(value) FILTER (WHERE element = 'TAVG') AS tavg
FROM   reports
GROUP  BY id_station, date
ORDER  BY id_station, date;
```

The aggregate `FILTER` clause requires Postgres 9.4. Details and alternatives for older versions:

- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)

For more columns of for lots of rows (and you need better performance), consider an actual `crosstab()` query. The special difficulty is that your *key* consists of two columns, but you need *one* for `crosstab()`. Generate a surrogate key with `row_number()` like in these related answers:

- [Pull data from multiple tables in a view or function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71236/pull-data-from-multiple-tables-in-a-view-or-function/71266#71266)
- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860)
- [Crosstab function in Postgres returning a one row output when I expect multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32918155/939860)